# Function: if either x or y are null, return null

Tags: oracle, functions, null, case, oracle-18c

I'm looking for an Oracle 18c function that evaluates to null if either of two variables is null.

> **The Constraints:** (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320558/function-for-a-function-based-spatial-index-if-x-not-null-and-y-not-null-cant))
>
> - The function/expression can't contain spaces (so CASE won't work).
> - I can't create a custom function due to insufficient privileges.

I've technically found a way to do this with NVL2(). But I doubt the `x+y` part is acceptable from a code quality point of view.

```
with cte as (
select    1 as x,    2 as y from dual
union all
select null as x,    3 as y from dual
union all
select null as x, null as y from dual
)
select
    x,
    y,
    -- Since anything + null = null, that means if either x or y are null, then the result will be null.
    nvl2(x+y,'no_nulls',null) as if_nulls_return_null
from
    cte
```

| X | Y | IF_NULLS_RETURN_NULL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | no_nulls |
| null | 3 | null |
| null | null | null |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f11a32e5ed1b3474522730890d44ecd)

Is there a clean way to `return null if either x or y is null` using an out-of-box function (and without spaces)?

**Edit:**

It turns out that it's **not** necessary to add a record to ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA when using the function-based spatial index in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1.

Comment: What a silly requirement: no spaces. Anyway, I see no problem with using `x+y`, that is just fine.

Comment: You shouldn't cross-post your questions.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that limits you from having spaces in the definition of the function. The [only limitation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/geometry-metadata-views.htm#SPATL545) is the **name** of the column in the spacial index can't contain spaces. So I'm not sure how a CASE statement or any other logical check would be an issue.

> The column **name** cannot contain spaces or mixed-case letters in a
> quoted string when inserted into the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view, and
> it cannot be in a quoted string when used in a query (unless it is in
> all uppercase characters).

Also I think it's just fine to use the X+Y syntax to check either value for null, as long as you use appropriate naming and comments to make the code readable.

Comment: You'll have to pardon my ignorance: I can't seem to figure out how to successfully wrap the function (function-based spatial index) in a **CASE** statement. I get an error when I try to create the index. Details here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN6GN.png. ... Any hints?

Comment: Not an Oracle expert here, but reading the manual, my understanding is, "The column name" stands for the value of the `COLUMN_NAME` column of the `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` view, which can be either an actual column name or, as in the OP's case, an expression, but it's still referred to as a column name. So I'm guessing the OP's interpretation might be correct in that the expression must not have spaces in it. But again, I'm no expert, so please take this with an appropriate amount of salt.

Comment: @AndriyM I think you're on to something (I'm also no expert on this) but I believe if the function exists, then it's just the calling of that function (the function name itself and any parameters passed in) that would need to not have spaces when used in an expression for the column name. So it shouldn't matter what the contents of the function itself are, in regards to type of characters used in the body of the function. So in short, if OP could make a new function he could do whatever he wanted (though I'm seeing conflicting information in both his posts to understand if he can or can't).

Answer (score -2):

You can use the **`greatest`** function for your purposes:

```
WITH s AS (
SELECT 1 AS nx, 1 AS ny FROM dual
UNION
SELECT NULL AS nx, 1 AS ny FROM dual
UNION
SELECT NULL as nx, NULL as ny FROM dual)
SELECT s.*
     , GREATEST (s.nx, s.ny) AS nresult
FROM   s;
```

Results:

| nx | ny | nresult |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| NULL | 1 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: You should add detail to your answer with example code, and perhaps a fiddle (see https://dbfiddle.uk)

Answer (score -4):

If x is null or y is null then null else 'no null'

Comment: Syntactically incorrect -- assuming you mean to use this as an expression.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that an `IF` statement cannot be used in the given context, the issue the OP is facing is how to check for nulls without using spaces in the expression. Your expression clearly has spaces between tokens: `If`, space, `x`, space, `is`, space etc. Indeed, in the linked SO question the OP has already tried a similar (but syntactically correct) expression which, however, also has spaces (`case when x is not null and y is not null then …`). Hence they are now asking for help with avoiding them.

Comment: But as the other answer indicates, spaces aren't a problem in the function but only in the name of the column.